# How to combine 3 equal-sized bitmaps into one bitmap, in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing

I have 3 equal-sized 8bit bitmaps. I want to make 8bit bitmap composed by the other 3. So, I want to convert 3 * 1440*1080 into 4320*1080.

Also, I want to "copy" them into the bigger image **one at a time** (basically because it's always the same image, just in different stages of processing).

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
unsigned char *img, *triple_img

//(all the allocations and what-not)

height = 1080;
width = 4320;

//first image
for (col = 0; col < width/3; col++) {
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        *(triple_img + row * width + col) = *(img + row * width/3 + col);
    }
}
//(...)

//second image
for (col = width/3; col < (width/3)*2; col++) {
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        *(triple_img + row * width + col) = *(img + row * width/3 + col - width);
    }
}
//(...)

//third image
for (col = (width/3)*2; col < width; col++) {
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        *(triple_img + row * width + col) = *(img + row * width/3 + col - 2 * width);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it?

**PS:** Okay, I noticed it doesn't work right after posting, cause `col` in `*img` will get out of bounds. I have to get a way of converting it to the right `col`.

**PS2:** Adding **-width** and **-2*width** to the `col` (respectively on 2nd and 3rd img) on the right side operand should work... I think.

**PS3:** It worked!

Comment: Why not simply try to see if it works?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just laziness, in all honesty. My images come from an image-capturing algorithm, that only works when connected to the camera. The camera itself is in a laboratory which I have limited access to. So, I wanted to make a code that works properly at the first time (or close to it), instead of writing another code to read some images from memory into pointers just to test this algorithm. But you're right, I'll do it.

Comment: you really should be using some decent abstractions for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz surely. But as you can see, I'm not the most experienced programmer. Care to explain what type of variables should I use for images?

Comment: For generic image handling I would recommend a library like OpenCV, or other similar image-handling library. It might even have the functionality you ask about (or at least a way to combine two images, which is enough to combine an infinite number of images really).

Comment: If the bitmaps are separated in `img`, then images 0, 1, and 2 start at offsets `0*row*width/3`, `1*row*width/3`, and `2*row*width/3`, and those are the amounts you would add to distinguish them, not `- width` and `- 2 * width`. However, your code suggests you are attempting to interleave rows of the bitmaps. That is unusual. Interleaving the individual pixels would be more common, such as combining red image, a green image, and a blue image into an RGB image.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't fully understand your comment. But I think you didn't understand my post either. So, I have only one image (`img`), a 1440*1080 greyscale bitmap. To that image are applied different steps of processing (greyscale value changes). After each step, I want to save a copy of the `img`. But, since I'm processing lots of `img`, to help me visualize the bigger picture (literally lol), I wanted to save those instances during processing into just one (for each `img`, of course).

Comment: @EricPostpischil so, the row X of `triple_img` should have the row X of `img` at stage 1 of processing, followed by the row X of `img` at stage 2, followed by the row X of `img` at stage 3. Hope this clears things up

Answer (score 0):

Least effort, obviously, is not to copy at all, but create the part images in the combined buffer.
Trivial if pixels are stored in the direction of abutment, so assuming pixels stored in rows:
You can still do "in-place creation" when creation requests buffer storage by the row.

Otherwise, use "bulk" copy by row.
For the `i`th image of `n` and `width` in bytes:

```
    pixel *destination = triple_img + image_width * i;
    for (int row = 0 ; row < height ; row++, destination += buffer_width)
        memcpy(destination, img + row * image_width, image_width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always think of a 1-D long row of bytes instead of 2-D col and row. In this way you have more control over how to find the offset to put second, third, ..., Nth bitmap on your final buffer.

Since you tag algorithm, I will give an advise.
Using inner loops cost performance and even worse when you did not too much care of making an alias for width/3 (perhaps you know how heavy would be division instructions down in machine code).

Comment: I try to do that, hence the `*(triple_img + row * width + col)` instead of triple_img[row][col]. But yes, I could apply that to the loops aswell. But I managed to solve my problem, through some excel visualization of indexes and stuff. And will take into account what you said about performance. Thanks